# Form editable database list?

Tags: html, database, list, database-design

I fear this may be a little out of my depth for online database management, but here goes.

I'd like to have a single page that lists every entry from a database in a list, displayed in a readable manner on a webpage. At the top of that webpage, I'd like a text entry box to add an additional entry to the top of the list.

I can make the form, the table and the list (frontend, at least), but creating, reading from and writing to that database are beyond me. Any good tips on where to begin with this?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  How do you communicate with it?  AJAX and SQL?

Comment: This sounds like a request for code-writing service. Please narrow down your question and show us your code samples highlighting the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: Definitely not asking anyone to do it for me! I don't have a code sample/language because, as I say in the question, this is something I'm new to - I was looking for a point in the right direction of where to learn about this.